# Monotone convergence theorem for increasing net of positive functions

Tags: measure-theory, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose that we have $(\Omega,\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space. I have the following question.
(Assume that $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be an increasing net of positive measurable functions such that $f_i\uparrow f$ pointwise. Suppose we know that $f$ is measurable. If $\sup_{i\in I}\int f_i$ is finite, can we say that $\int f$ is finite and $\lim_{i}\int f_i=\int f$? If not can it hold under the stronger assumption that $\int f$ is  finite?

Comment: The Dieudonné measure on $\omega_1$ is a counterexample.  Or, Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ under the continuum hypothesis CH: you may then write the constant function 1 as the pointwise limit of an increasing net of functions with countable support.

Comment: Take $I$ to be the set of finite subsets of $\Omega$, and assume that all singletons are measurable. The net $(\chi_{S})_{S \in I}$ is monotone and converges to the constant $1$ function pointwise (just follow the definition). So for any non-zero measure vanishing on singletons we have a counterexample.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a topological space, all open sets are measurable, and $f$ and all $f_i$ are lower semicontinuous, and you have a $\tau$-additive measure $\mu$, then this does hold. Radon measures, such as Lebesgue measure, are $\tau$-additive. The Dieudonné measure mentioned by Nate Eldredge is a classical non-$\tau$-additive measure.

Comment: @Robert. In your example $(\Chi_S)$. The limit is not integrable.

Comment: @Abeginnermathmatician Sorry, I didn't see that your measure was $\sigma$-finite and not finite. Let $Y$ be a measurable set with $0 < \mu(Y) < \infty$ (which exists for any non-zero $\sigma$-finite measure). Take $I$ to be the finite subsets of $Y$. The net $(\chi_S)_{S \in I}$ is monotone and converges pointwise to $\chi_Y$. So if all singletons in $Y$ are measurable with measure zero this is a counterexample.

Comment: @NateEldredge: where is the continuum hypothesis used in the Lebesgue measure example?

Comment: @WillieWong: If $\phi : \omega_1 \to [0,1]$ is a bijection, I was thinking of the net indexed by $I = \omega_1$, with $f_i : i \in I$ the indicator of the set $\{ \phi(j) : j < i\}$.  But Robert Furber's construction is simpler and better.